Is it correct? とともに and たまま
I was doing a lesson when I saw this question:

学校が＿＿＿子供たちが外で遊び始める

I put 終わったまま because I thought that this was an action that happened in the past. But the correct answer is 終わるとともに. I don't understand.

～まま means "remaining in that state". 終わったまま would mean "remaining in the finished state", "while it's still finished", or something similar. You can use it like 梱包が終わったままで発送していない ("The packaging is finished and left as is, you haven't shipped it yet"). In your context, 終わったままで doesn't make sense.
～とともに means "as soon as" or "right when", which is what you need here. Regarding the tense, the verb before とともに can be in either the present or the past tense. You probably know that 前に always takes the present tense and 後で always takes the past tense (here's why). In the case of とともに, it's a word that describes two events happening almost at the same time, so both tenses work interchangeably, and the difference is usually negligible.

学校が終わるとともに子供たちが外で遊び始める
= 学校が終わったとともに子供たちが外で遊び始める
As soon as school ends, the children start playing outside.

